# Добавить пробел между символами С++

Tags: c++

Необходимо добавить пробелы между символами вывода и записать их в строки

введите сюда код

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    const int N = 10000;
    vector<bool>simple(N, true);
    ofstream f("simple.txt");
    for (int i = 2; i * i <= N; ++i) {
        if (simple[i] == true) {
            for (int j = i * i; j < N; j += i) {
                //cout << j << " ";
                simple[j] = false;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 2; i < N; ++i) {
        if (simple[i] == true) {
            f << i << endl;
        }
    }



    cout << "Completed!";
}
```

Comment: А как-то немного более понятно можно описать, что вы хотите? И что такое "символы вывода"?

Comment: В чем Ваш вопрос? Записать сколько-то единиц в файл суд по коду?

Answer (score 0):

Вот так

```
 ...
 f <<" "<< i << " " << endl;
 ...
```

Comment: Скомпилировать пробовали?...

Comment: А зачем строки, если можно символы `' '`?

Comment: Опишите в чем разница. Если разницы нет, то выбор это дело вкуса